# OpenGL Shapes not appearing in ViewPort

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.x, opengl, rendering

I'm fairly new to openGL, and (from researching) I THINK I understand the whole viewport vs frustum difference... but I'm not sure if I have things configured/set up correctly - a 2nd (or 10th) set of eyes to look at my code would help.  I'm using Python 3.5 in Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition) with PyOpenGL (3.1.0).

I am attempting to render just a simple sphere:

Using values:

```
self._left = 0.
self._right = 400.
self._bottom = 0.
self._top = 400.
self._width = self._right - self._left (400.)
self._height = self._top - self._bottom (400.)
self._ratio = self._width / self._height (1.)
self._spheres = []
```

A single sphere object gets appended to the _spheres list with center at (200, 200, 0) and radius 20

I configure openGL:

```
glut.glutInit(sys.argv)
glut.glutInitDisplayMode(glut.GLUT_RGBA | glut.GLUT_DOUBLE | glut.GLUT_DEPTH)
glut.glutInitWindowSize(int(self._width), int(self._height))
glut.glutInitWindowPosition(int((1920 - self._width) * .05), int((1080 - self._height) * .80))
glut.glutCreateWindow(b'WindowName')
gl.glClearColor(0., 0., 0., 1.) # Use solid black when clearing the buffer (results in black background)
gl.glShadeModel(gl.GL_SMOOTH) # Have the coloring of faces be smooth (gradient between lighting values at the verticies) vs a solid color
gl.glEnable(gl.GL_CULL_FACE) # Don't render triangles and other shapes (?) which are not visible to the camera
gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST) # Enable depth testing for objects .. enables 3-dimensional drawing?..
gl.glEnable(gl.GL_LIGHTING) # Use lights to determine what color objects are (if no vertex shader is active)
# Configure Lighting
gl.lightZeroPosition = [self._width / 2, self._height / 2, -500., 1.] # create a variable ... (python specific) associate it with gl dictionary in case you want to access it somewhere else later..
gl.lightZeroColor = [0.8, 1.0, 0.8, 1.0] # create a variable ... (python specific) associate it with gl dictionary in case you want to access it somewhere else later.. green tinged light
gl.glLightfv(gl.GL_LIGHT0, gl.GL_POSITION, gl.lightZeroPosition) # set configuration for light0 (position)
gl.glLightfv(gl.GL_LIGHT0, gl.GL_DIFFUSE, gl.lightZeroColor) # set configuration for light0 (color of light)
gl.glLightf(gl.GL_LIGHT0, gl.GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 0.01) # set configuration for light0 (light gets less bright farther away)
gl.glLightf(gl.GL_LIGHT0, gl.GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.005) # set configuration for light0 (light gets less bright farther away)
gl.glEnable(gl.GL_LIGHT0) # Include light0 in the GL_LIGHTING calculation
# Configure visual area values
# Make viewport dimensions the same as the window
gl.glViewport(0, 0, int(self._width), int(self._height))
gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
gl.glLoadIdentity()
# frustum has near points same as window (so shapes don't get warped), but far points to go well beyond sphere location (which sphere should exist in)
gl.glFrustum(self._left, self._right, self._bottom, self._top, 100, 700)
# Configure rendering values
gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
self._eyePosition = Point3D("Camera Eye Location").translate(int(self._width / 2), int(self._height / 2), -400)
self._watchingPosition = Point3D("Camera Watching Position").translate(int(self._width / 2), int(self._height / 2), 0)
self._upVector = Point3D("Camera Up Vector").translate(0, 1, 0)
glu.gluLookAt(self._eyePosition.x, self._eyePosition.y, self._eyePosition.z,
              self._watchingPosition.x, self._watchingPosition.y, self._watchingPosition.z,
              self._upVector.x, self._upVector.y, self._upVector.z)
gl.glPushMatrix()
```

I register my callbacks:

```
glut.glutDisplayFunc(self.paint)
glut.glutIdleFunc(self.repaint)
```

Finally I start the mainLoop:

```
glut.glutMainLoop()
```

The window shows, but nothing is drawn in the viewport.  :/

Here is my paint method:

```
def paint(self):
    elapsedTime = 0
    currentTime = time.clock()
    if self._lastTime is not None:
        elapsedTime = currentTime - self._lastTime
    self._lastTime = currentTime
    gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    self._drawSpheres(elapsedTime)
    glut.glutSwapBuffers()
    return
```

My repaint method:

```
def repaint(self):
    glut.glutPostRedisplay()
    return
```

And my drawSpheres method:

```
def _drawSpheres(self, elapsedTime):
    if self._spheres is not None:
        for sphere in self._spheres:
            # Remove any changes to matrix from previous drawing by pop.. preserve stack, so push immediately
            # This should be fine, since I pushed to stack in my initialization to save my visual and rendering area values.
            gl.glPopMatrix()
            gl.glPushMatrix()
            sphereCenter = sphere.currentLocation # As stated above - this is (200, 200, 0)
            sphereRadius = sphere.radius # As stated above - this is 20
            sphereColor = sphere.color # Not stated above, but this is (1., 0., 0., 1.)
            gl.glTranslate(sphereCenter.x, sphereCenter.y, sphereCenter.z)
            gl.glMaterialfv(gl.GL_FRONT, gl.GL_DIFFUSE, [sphereColor.getRedAsPercent(), sphereColor.getGreenAsPercent(), sphereColor.getBlueAsPercent(), sphereColor.getAlphaAsPercent()])
            glut.glutSolidSphere(sphereRadius, 15, 15)
            sphere.move(elapsedTime)
    return
```

Any assistance is appreciated.  :)

Comment: Some advices: missing spheres coordinates; do not pop matrix if the stack is empty; disable lighting and other things to simplify debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you're setting the perspective matrix badly.

See the link below:

https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/calculating-the-gluperspective-matrix-and-other-opengl-matrix-maths/

You can see the gluPerspective implementation is based on FoV angles. Study that explanation. Using glFrustum allows you to setup an asymmetric perspective projection, which is not used frequently in this cases.

Comment: Hmm...  I changed my glFrustum() to gluPerspective() and everything is magically working now.  >.> `gluPerspective(30., self._width / self._height, 100, 700)` .. why is this so much different than me declaring the frustum directly?  (I was under the impression that gluPerspective was just a shortcut to doing the frustum yourself, and that the FoV/aspect was used to calculate the the left/right/top/bottom values for frustum..)

Comment: Study the link that I provided. Your impression is correct, but you have to do some math to understand the magic behind it. You can start by investigating on gluPerspective implementation.